# gcrt1.S:195: multiple definition of `__bad_interrupt'

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217429/avr-gcc-variable-must-be-const-in-order-to-be-put-into-read-only-section-by-mea), but a different approach.

I am trying to reproduce this [4-key-keyboard](http://blog.flipwork.nl/?x=entry:entry100224-003937)  and for that I am trying to compile [its source](http://blog.flipwork.nl/fp-content/attachs/4-key-keyboard.zip) by compiling it with avr-gcc on my Linux box.

To solve compiler issues with current version of avr-gcc, I downloaded the [latest release (20121206)](http://www.obdev.at/downloads/vusb/vusb-20121206.tar.gz) of the V-USB library, replaced the old version `usbdrv` with the new version `usbdrv` in the 4-key-keyboard source tree.

To compile the code I changed line 105 in `main.c` from `PROGMEM char` to `PROGMEM const char` and compile the source code with the following command:

```
avr-gcc main.c -I /usr/lib/avr/include/ -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16000000 -Os -I ./usbdrv -I . usbdrv/usbdrv.c usbdrv/usbdrvasm.S -o main.o
```

To the best of my knowledge, the next step is to create an .elf file. I use the following command for that:

```
avr-gcc -I /usr/lib/avr/include/ -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16000000 -Os -I ./usbdrv -I . -o main.elf main.o
```

But it throws errors:

```
main.o: In function `__bad_interrupt':
../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S:195: multiple definition of `__bad_interrupt'
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/lib/avr25/crttn85.o:../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S:195: first defined here
main.o: In function `__vectors':
../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S:52: multiple definition of `__vectors'
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.7.2/../../../avr/lib/avr25/crttn85.o:../../../../crt1/gcrt1.S:195: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Both `__bad_interrupt` and `__vectors` refer to the microcontroller's interrupt vector table. It seems to be an issue/misuse with the standard avr libraries, but I can't figure out how these would be linked in twice. As a matter of fact I cannot even locate a file named `gcrt1.S` on my system.

Question is: How can I solve these errors and what is the cause?

**edit**: It seems that adding the `-nostartfiles` flag with the second avr-gcc command solves the issue, but why was have I never had before the need for including that parameter when compiling for AVR? When I add the flag to one of my own simple ATtiny programs, the vector table is no longer included at all.
(thanks to @angelatlarge)

So new question: Why does the need for this `-nostartfiles` parameter come from, what causes it?

Answer (score 2):

You already fully compiled your code in the first step. If you want to change or add object files later you should compile your code relocatable. In other words, in your first command you should add the -c flag (note you have to run gcc separately for every file with -c, you can't supply more then 1 file if you compile with -c).

In this case it doesn't seem to be necessary though, you can directly continue from the first step without using the -c flag. All you have to do after doing step 1 (without -c, that is) is run something like avr-objcopy to shoot everything into an intel hex file (.hex) or whichever binary format you are using before you upload your code to the chip.

Now, if you want to further understand what happens during the compilation process and the difference between compiling WITH -c and without I suggest the following. Make a very simple source file, something like:

```
int main(void)
{
     while(1);
}
```

Assume you called the above source example test.c and compile twice:

```
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=attiny85 -o test-with-c.o
avr-gcc -mmcu-attiny85 -o test-no-c.o
```

Then dump both files:

```
avr-objdump -DSx test-no-c.o > test-no-c.dmp
avr-objdump -DSx test-with-c.o > test-with-c.dmp
```

Now open the dump files in vim, gedit or whatever and compare them. Now you should be able to reason why you cannot link two object files together if they are both compiled without the relocation flag (which is what you were trying to do, with the second command).

Comment: I compared the files in vimdiff, and I see a lot of differences (esp. the vector table), but I'n not entirely sure what you are aiming at in your last sentence. I'll have to sit down this weekend to try better understand what is happening and what the difference is between using `-c` and using `-nostartfiles`.

Comment: What -c and -nostartfiles both do, is not providing 'all those differences' (i.e. no vector table, __bad_interrupt label, etc etc). It basically creates an object file for you with ONLY the code you wrote. However, thats not even near bootable. To be able to boot your program you need the vector table etc, etc, but you need it only once.